# How to instantiate a custom session

Tags: magento-1.7, session, singleton

I'm working on a module with a custom `namespace session`. I extended the `Session class` and created a new object, but every time I use the new object it overwrites the parent one while I need 2 different instances

Can a custom session be instantiated twice ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it, the extended class should override the parent method `__construct`
and use a different namespace

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $namespace = 'different_name_from_parent';
        $this->init($namespace);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('event_name', array('session_name'=>$this));
    }
```

Otherwise `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::init()` will merge the data array from the parent session

```
$this->_data = &$_SESSION[$namespace];
```

and the result is a copy of the same object